# I would like to generate cross reference for my own linux kernel working folder

Tags: c, gcc, linux-kernel, cross-reference, lxr

I am working on a linux kernel, and I would like to generate my own cross reference pages for the working folder....similar to what is found [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/).

So, obviously the question is....how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[LXR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lxr/)

Linux Cross Referencer
From that site:

Description:
A general purpose source code indexer and cross-referencer that provides web-based browsing of source code with links to the definition and usage of any identifier. Supports multiple languages. Up-to-date information in http://lxr.sourceforge.net

Comment: So your link wasn't working for me.  You already referenced LXR.  Apologies.